# Macos default paths prepend my defined paths in vim

Tags: vim, shell, path

I am trying to call some shell command from vim with like `:!ls` command.
But unfortunately there are some default PATHS that prepends PATHs defined in the original shell. Here is the `echo $PATH` output in the original shell:

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/bogdan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/bogdan/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/bogdan/.rvm/bin:/Users/bogdan/bin:/Users/bogdan/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.12.2/libexec/git-core:/Users/bogdan/.rvm/bin
```

and shell called within vim:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@devauc/bin:/Users/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/bogdan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/bogdan/.rvm/bin:/Users/bogdan/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.12.2/libexec/git-core:/Users/bogdan/.rvm/bin
```

Why they appeared right there? How can I prevent that and make vim shell has original PATH variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092347/how-to-make-vim-use-the-same-environment-as-my-login-shell-when-running-commands/9092644#9092644) or [this one with a nice table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716849/commands-available-in-bash-i-cant-access-in-bash-l/9717572#9717572) to similar questions. You should check the file in which you setup your custom `$PATH`. Whether it's `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` or some other file *and* the method of invocation of the shell have their role in this.

For reference, I have only one line in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
source ~/.profile
```

(with all my settings going into `~/.profile`) and this line in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set shell=bash\ -i
```

The whole thing is not very pretty but it's simple and it works.